# OAuth returns bad request message

Tags: php

I am trying to generate a token using OAuth 2.0

I redirect the user to the given URL,
User logs in, grants permission,
and then user is returned to my RETURN_URL

Below is the code for my RETURN_URL, and it gives following error:

```
{"code":400,"status":"Bad Request","timestamp":"2018-11-06T17:41:08+05:30","message":"Bad Request","error":{"reason":"Something wrong in request"}}
$code= $_GET[code];
$url = 'https://api.example.com/index/oauth/token';

$auth = $API_KEY.":".$API_SECRET ;

$header = array();
 $header[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
 $header[] = 'x-api-key: '.$API_KEY;
 $header[] = 'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($auth);

$data = array(
 'code' => $code,
 'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
 'redirect_uri' => $RETURN_URL
 );


$data = trim(http_build_query($data));

$ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $API_KEY.":".$API_SECRET );
 //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
 //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$API_KEY:$API_SECRET" );

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 $result= curl_exec($ch);
 $error = curl_error($ch);

echo $result; exit;

curl_close($ch);
```

This is what their docs are saying for required parameters:

```
curl \
-u {your_api_key}:{your_api_secret} \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'x-api-key: {your_api_key}' \
-d '{"code" : "{code_from_login_response}", "grant_type" : "authorization_code", "redirect_uri" : "{your_redirect_uri}"}' \
```

Comment: You will have to look at their API docs to understand what is missing.

Comment: Hi, I added info about what their docs are saying about required parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting a 400 bad request is because the API server that you are hitting is unable to understand the `$data` you sent and JSON decode it. Hence, below steps might help in sending a proper POST request with proper JSON-

- Change `$_GET[code]` to `$_GET['code']`. It works without the single quotes but it does generate a `notice of undefined constant 'code'`. Also, you might want to filter this data for security reasons.
- remove `$data = trim(http_build_query($data));`.
- Change this line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );` to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) );` and you should be good to go.

The reason why this might be happening as far as I see is because probably API Server you are hitting is receiving your JSON data as `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');`, kind of like a webhook. So, when you made a request, it wasn't able to parse your data as JSON and hence sent you a bad request error.

Comment: I cannot tell you how much thankful I am to you for this help :) :) Deeply greatful, many many thanks! May GOD bless you brother :)

Comment: @SumitKumar Thank you. Glad to help. Happy coding :)